# Add/Remove Clone Append and while showing price for each selection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

Hi World of backend programmers! 
I would really appreciate if someone could assist me. 
I'm building a form and managed to get as far as to clone and set up the arithmetic.

My dilemma is that when it clones, the remove function does not work nor do each clone retain its individual number (instead the numbers are added to the original).

Again I hope someone can help me with this challenge, because I am stomped. :(

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
            if(count < 3) {
        $("#clone").clone(true).appendTo("#fspace2");
            count++;
        }
$("#minus").click(function () {
    .remove().clone(true);
});
    });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var basePrice = 6.25;
   $(".calculate").change(function () {
     newPrice = basePrice;
    $(".calculate option:selected").each(function () {
       newPrice += Number($(this).data('price'));
    });
   $("#item-price").html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
    });
});
</script>

<div id="clone">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:1em;">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title"></td>

            <td style="padding-bottom:1em;">
            <label for="title">Price:</label>
            <span id="item-price">0.00</span><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

                                    <table id="line">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="titlecust" style="text-align: center; width:2em;">Options &amp; Packages</td>
                                            <td class="titlecust" style="text-align: center; width: 13em;">Color Scheme</td>
                                            <td class="titlecust" style="text-align: center; margin-left: 2em; width: 10em;">Dimensions</td>
                                            <td class="titlecust" style="text-align: center;">File Type 1</td>
                                            <td class="titlecust" style="text-align: center;">File Type 2</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="cellspace">
                                <!--**OPT - Come back to fix spacing-->
                                                <select class="form-control calculate" id="try" name="try">
                                                    <option data-price="0" value="select">Select an Option</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="logo1">Logo</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="bro">Brochure(6pages)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="web1">Website(static)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="web2">Website(dynamic)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="ill">Illustration</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="fly1">Flyer(text)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="fly2">Flyer(text/illustrate)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="temp1">Template(flyer)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="temp2">Template(website)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="photo1">Photography(3hours)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="photo1">Photography(6hours)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="photo1">Photography(8hours)</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="ban">Banner</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="hand">Handbill</option>
                                                    <option data-price="25" value="buscard">Business Card</option>
                                                    <option data-price="N/A" value="oth">Other</option>
                                                </select><br /><br />
                                                <select class="form-control calculate" id="packaging" name="packaging">
                                                <option data-price="0" value="standard">Choose a Package</option>
                                                <option data-price="50.00" value="shrink">Business Starter</option>
                                                <option data-price="50.00" value="shrink">Website Starter</option>
                                               </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="cellspace">
                                                <script src="_js/jscolor1.js"></script>
                                                    Color 1:<input class="jscolor {mode:'HSV',position:'right'}">
                                                    Color 2:<input class="jscolor {mode:'HSV',position:'right'}">
                                                    Color 3:<input class="jscolor {mode:'HSV',position:'right'}">



                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="number" name="dimen1" id="dimen1" style="width:4em; margin-top:1em;">
                                            &ensp; X
                                                <input type="number" name="dimen2" id="dimen2" style="width:4em; margin-top:1em;">
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="cellspace">
                                                <select>
                                                    <option value="jpeg">.jpeg</option>
                                                    <option value="jpeg">.jpeg2000</option>
                                                    <option value="tiff">.tiff</option>
                                                    <option value="gif">.gif</option>
                                                    <option value="bmp">.bmp</option>
                                                    <option value="png">.png</option>
                                                    <option value="eps">.eps</option>
                                                    <option value="pdf">.pdf</option>
                                                    <option value="pbm">.pbm</option>
                                                    <option value="psd">.psd</option>
                                                    <option value="ai">.ai</option>
                                                    <option value="indd">.indd</option>
                                                    <option value="dwt">.dwt</option>
                                                    <option value="other1">other</option>
                                                </select><br>

                                                <!--<input type="text" size="12" placeholder="if other..."></input>-->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <tr>

                            <div id="float1" style="float: left;"><input type="button" id="add" value="Add Project"></div>
                            <div id="float2" style="float: left;"><input type="button" id="minus" value="Subtract Project"></div>
                            <br><br><hr />

                        </fieldset>
                        <div id="float" style="float: right;"><input type="submit" id="join" name="join" value="Submit">
                            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></div><br />
                    </form>
            </section>
            </div>
```

Update Fiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/YourAce17/HQ964/69/#&togetherjs=PIlR2o5VVw

Comment: 1. Do not use IDs when cloning an element. Use class names, otherwise the codes will not work after the first cloning.

2. I don't see any remove functions in your code.

3. Your code is not complete.

Comment: Okay Updated it; also I will go in to try to make classes. But the issue isn't that it will not clone enough. the issue is that when I clone, I cannot remove and the arithmetic for each selection will not retain.

Comment: Could you please add a demo `fiddle` or `snippet` replicating the problem?

Comment: *"But the issue isn't that it will not clone enough. the issue is that when I clone, I cannot remove and the arithmetic for each selection will not retain. "* The symptoms you describe plus the obvious fact that you are cloning #ids looking at your code, it is definitely the reason. Example: There are 4 guys named Joe and you want one of them to leave because you can't stand him. So when you say, *"Hey Joe, get lost". All 4 guys named Joe assume you must be talking to one of the other guys named Joe, since they each believe they are the most likable of all of the Joes.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I updated it and added a fiddle. But like both you, zer00ne and Gel said: it is most likely because I'm using ids because fiddle won't allow any of my functions. I'm going to try to go in today and use classes and try to update this code so it will work better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/YourAce17/HQ964/69/#&togetherjs=PIlR2o5VVw